# How to change log level of userlogs in Hadoop 2?

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, log4j, hadoop2

I've been trying to change the log level on userlogs i.e the files that appear under `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_<id>/container_<id>` on CDH 5.2.1.  However, no matter what I try, only `INFO` level logs will appear.  I want to enable `TRACE` level logs for debugging.

Things I have tried so far:

- Setting all loggers to TRACE level in `/etc/hadoop/conf/log4j.properties`.
- Setting `mapreduce.map.log.level` and `mapreduce.reduce.log.level` in `mapred-site.xml`.
- Setting `mapreduce.map.log.level` and `mapreduce.reduce.log.level` in the job configuration before submitting it.
- Including a `log4j.properties` in my job jar file that sets the root Log4j logger to TRACE.
- Modifying `yarn-env.sh` to specify `YARN_ROOT_LOGGER=TRACE,console`

None of these worked -- they didn't break anything, but they didn't have any effect on the log outputs under the `userlogs` directory.  Modifying yarn-env.sh *did* cause the ResourceManager and NodeManager logs to enter trace level.  Unfortunately these are not useful for my purpose.

I get the following error appearing in `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_<id>/container_<id>/stderr` that may be relevant.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/tomcat/appcache/application_1419961570089_0001/filecache/10/job.jar/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I don't understand why the log4j "no configuration" message would happen, given that there is a `log4j.properties` file at the root of the job jar file that specifies a root logger:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] %m%n
```

My code does not knowingly use SLF4J for logging, it purely uses Log4j.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual answer was to set `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.log.level` to the level you need, but, crucially, it needs to be set in the Hadoop job configuration at submission time.  It cannot be set on the cluster globally.  The cluster global will always default to `INFO`, as it is hardcoded.

Using `container-log4j.properties` alone will not work as YARN will override the log level value on the command line.  See the method `addLog4jSystemProperties` of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps` and cross reference with `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MRJobConfig`.

`container-log4j.properties` will indeed be honoured, but it can't override the level set by this property.

Answer (score 2):

On CDH5.8, I am overwriting the application log level at job submission time. To modify the log level of the mappers and reducers, I had to specify them explicitly using a command like this:

hadoop jar my-mapreduce-job.jar -libjars ${LIBJARS} **-Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.log.level=DEBUG,console** **-Dmapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG,console** **-Dmapreduce.reduce.log.level=DEBUG,console**

The logs are written to the applications's syslog which can be browsed using the Yarn ResourceManager Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to edit (or create if it does'nt exist) : /etc/hadoop/conf/container-log4j.properties.

You can see it with a simple `ps aux` : the command line includes `-Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties`.

Comment: This did seem to have some effect, in that it removed the "syslog" file from the container log directory.  However, that's all that happened.  I used the [example properties file](https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/2942a5bfbafd67655b0859d339a4e95a0b6d5044/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/resources/container-log4j.properties) that I found through Google. I have real clue what this is attempting to do though.

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct values for these parameters should be, if I only want to change the log level in the 'syslog' file.